# My 04 Subaru Forester takes off like I have the A/C on and I’m going up a steep hill... no power!

Tags: subaru, power, forester

This just started yesterday. The check engine light has been on forever but none of the mechanics in my area can seem to figure out what the problem is or how to fix it so I’ve just been driving around with the light on my dash. Once in a while the airbags light will come on, but then it turns off for longer than it was on. The major problem is the lack of power. I read a post here which had several different suggestions for repair, but let me tell you the situation...

I waited a few minutes before driving so as not to drive on a freezing engine. I live off a highway, so pulling out is fun but never an issue because my Forester has always had get up and go. Yesterday however, I pulled out, floored the accelerator and felt like I was riding in a bumper car! I even checked to see if my A/C was on because that has taken its fair share of power in the past, but it was off. History on my car, several years back, I took it to Walmart to have the oil changed and the moron forgot to refill the oil. So I end up about 60 miles from home and suddenly I hear knocking coming from my engine and my heart breaks! I stop, check the oil and it’s barely marking the dipstick! Walmart was willing to work with me however I ended up in the hospital for a few weeks and in bed rest for a few more and by the time I was able to get back with the manager, he was no longer with Walmart and the new manager would not help me. So now I drive a forester that makes a knocking sound - but that’s when I know I need to add some more Lucas (:

So can anyone help me on this? I’m hoping it’s just a tuneup and not any of the sensors but with my luck...

Comment: I'd start with just getting the codes pulled and see what pops up. Also, a note about ac here, if you had the defroster on most vehicles will also run the AC in order to dry the air.

Comment: I plan in taking it to O’Reillys the next time they are open and have them run a diagnostic. I’ll supply you the codes at that time. As far as the A/C, the entire was off... no blowing, no lights but boy so I wish that was the problem! Totally simple fix. I’ll respond with codes as soon as I have them. 

Thanks a million for your help!

Comment: My pleasure. I always throw out suggestions such as that just because I'm always surprised by what people don't know. Anyways, best of luck, please do keep us aware so we can help if possible.

Comment: When was the last time that the air filter has been replaced? After the oil incident, have you checked the health of the engine by performing a Dyno run, a compression test and a leak down test?

Comment: You're in trouble. Knocking doesn't need a code. Start saving for another car. If you are inclined to spend some money have a compression test done. Possibly your no-oil run has damaged a piston ring or warped a cylinder head. If you lose one piston's compression (in a 4 cylinder) your power goes away, good luck.